# Trouble setting up NVIM (ncm2-phpactor) Plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I used to work in vim but I find out that autocompletion in nvim using ncm2-phpactor is so much better than vim's YouCompleteMe so I just set up nvim today but I am facing this problem in one of my laravel project. Every time I try to write some code inside the controller or any other PHP file it throws an error.

```
[ncm2_phpactor@yarp] json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**Environment**

NVIM:

```
NVIM v0.4.0-126-g88963a18d
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.0.5
Compilation: /usr/bin/cc -Wshadow -Wconversion -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -O2 -DNDEBUG -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fdiagnostics-color=auto -Wno-array-bounds -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -I/home/talha/neovim/build/config -I/home/talha/neovim/src -I/home/talha/neovim/.deps/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/home/talha/neovim/build/src/nvim/auto -I/home/talha/neovim/build/include
Compiled by talha@talha-XPS-13-9360

Features: +acl +iconv +jemalloc +tui 
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

PHP:

```
PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Sep 13 2018 13:45:02) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

.VIMRC or ~/.config/nvim/init.vim:

```
if empty(glob('~/.config/nvim/autoload/plug.vim'))
    silent !curl -fLo ~/.config/nvim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
                \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall
endif

call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged')
Plug 'ncm2/ncm2'
Plug 'roxma/nvim-yarp'
Plug 'roxma/vim-hug-neovim-rpc'

Plug 'phpactor/phpactor' ,  {'do': 'composer install', 'for': 'php'}
Plug 'phpactor/ncm2-phpactor'
Plug 'ncm2/ncm2-ultisnips'
Plug 'ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags'
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips' | Plug 'phux/vim-snippets'
call plug#end()

let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<c-j>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-j>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-b>"

" PHP7
let g:ultisnips_php_scalar_types = 1

augroup ncm2
  au!
  autocmd BufEnter * call ncm2#enable_for_buffer()
  set completeopt=noinsert,menuone,noselect
  au User Ncm2PopupOpen set completeopt=noinsert,menuone,noselect
  au User Ncm2PopupClose set completeopt=menuone
augroup END

" parameter expansion for selected entry via Enter
inoremap <silent> <expr> <CR> (pumvisible() ? ncm2_ultisnips#expand_or("\<CR>", 'n') : "\<CR>")

" cycle through completion entries with tab/shift+tab
inoremap <expr> <TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<c-n>" : "\<TAB>"
inoremap <expr> <s-tab> pumvisible() ? "\<c-p>" : "\<TAB>"
```

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install composer --> [1]: https://getcomposer.org/download/
2. Make it global --> [2]: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally
3. Follow instructions --> [3]: https://phpactor.github.io/phpactor/vim-plugin.html

That should be it!
Cheers!

Comment: Composer in installed and global. And I have already followed all the instructions (no luck). Well I configured https://github.com/lvht/phpcd.vim and its working quite good for me.

Comment: If you are still getting that specific error, it means that you are probably missing some libraries. Did you do this: $ cd ~/.config/nvim/plugged/phpactor
$ composer install

Comment: Plug 'phpactor/phpactor' ,  {'do': 'composer install', 'for': 'php'} .vim-plug did that for me when I run :PlugInstall